# JPA relación ManyToMany con una vista de sólo lectura como entidad

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo una relación ManyToMany entre una tabla (PROCESO) y una vista de sólo lectura FUNCIONINTEGRADA. Estas son las dos entidades:
La primera

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROCESO")
public class Proceso extends Auditable<Long> {

   /* Otros campos */
   @JoinTable(
       name = "PROCESO_RESP",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDPROCESO", nullable = false),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="IDRESPONSABLE", nullable = false)
   )
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<FuncionIntegrada> responsables=new ArrayList<FuncionIntegrada>();

   /* Getters y setters */
}
```

Y esta es la segunda entidad:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FUNCIONINTEGRADA")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class FuncionIntegrada extends Auditable<Integer> {

   /* Otros campos */

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "responsables")
   private List<Proceso> procesos;

   /* Getters y setters */
```

}

Como podéis ver, es necesario que la vista sea sólo de lectura (es muy importante no escribir en esta vista). ¿Cómo puedo hacer un update de un proceso con su lista de responsables sin escribir en la vista "FUNCIONINTEGRADA"?
Cuando hago un update del proceso con la lista de responsables, intenta escribir en la vista "FUNCIONINTEGRADA" y se produce una excepción porque, obviamente, no puede escribir en la vista. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: un many to many deberia tener una tabla intermedia con las claves primarias de cada tabla

Comment: Ya la tiene. La tabla intermedia es la que se llama "PROCESO_RESP". Está bien implementada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era eliminar el (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) del @ManyToMany de la clase Proceso. Con esto ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FUNCIONINTEGRADA")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class FuncionIntegrada extends Auditable<Integer> {

   /* Otros campos */

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "responsables")
   @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private List<Proceso> procesos;

   /* Getters y setters */
```